# Change the label name dynamically in angular js getting value from angular controller

Tags: arrays, angularjs, dynamic, label

> Hi friends , I am trying to design security question window which will
>   have 3 question but one after another on the same window depending
>   upon the button click. In my example I have confirm button after click
>   it will send answer and question id to back end spring controller. If
>   answer is not correct then I have to display next question on the same
>   window and like wise for 3 questions.And I am not able to show next
>   question.There are two arrays in my code listOfUserQuesValues[] for security
>    question and listOfUserQuesKey[] contains key of that question.Both contains 3 values.
>
> Security_Question.jsp
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
> ```
>
> var app = angular.module('formSubmit'[]);
>   app.controller('forgotController',
>   ['$scope','$http','$location',function($scope, $http,$location) 
>               {
>               $scope.Id=0;
>               $scope.listOfUserQuesValues=[];
>               $scope.listOfUserQuesKey=[];
>
> ```
>        //gets the  user question by matching user id
>         $scope.getUserQuestions=function()
>         {
>          var url = $location.search(); //read id from url
>          angular.forEach(url,function(value,key)
>                {
>                $scope.Id=parseInt(value); //cuurent id
>              })
>                var userId=$scope.Id;
> ```

$http.get('loginController/getUserQuestions/'+userId).success(function(data,

> status, headers, config) {
>                                   angular.forEach(data,function(value,key){
>                                 $scope.listOfUserQuesKey.push(key);
>                                 $scope.listOfUserQuesValues.push(value);
>
> ```
>                           })
>
>                       })
>                       .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
>                           alert( "Exception details: " +data+"  "+status);
>                       }); 
>             }//getUserQuestions
>
>
>             //checkj for valid answer
>            $scope.checkAnswer=function(answer)
>            {
>               var ans= {
>                           "answer" :answer,
>                         "security_question_id":$scope.listOfUserQuesKey[0]
>                         //here assigning question Id of first question bt             this should be dynamically pass 1st then 2 then 3rd
>                            };
>
>                   var response = $http.post('loginController/checkAnswer',ans);
>               response.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
>                               if(data=true)
>                     window.alert("Password has been sent to your mail id successfullly ! ")                       else
>     // here its has to get same window but with next question                         
>                   });
>                   response.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
>                       alert( "Exception details: " +data+"  "+status);
>                   });
>
>            }
>
>             //cancel
>            $scope.cancel=function()
>            {
>
>                 window.alert("cancel");
>                $("#myModal").modal('hide');
>                   window.location="./forgotpassword.jsp? "; 
>
>            }
>
>       } ]);
> ```
>
> Html code of security_Question.jsp
>
> ```
>   <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px"
>       data-ng-init="getUserQuestions()">          <div
>           class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-3">
>           <form role="form" name="myform">
>               <fieldset>
>                   <h3>Password Recovery Security Question</h3>
>                   <hr class="colorgraph">
>
>
>                   <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
>                       <div class="modal-dialog">
>                           <div class="modal-content">
>                               <div class="modal-header">
>                                   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
>                                       aria-hidden="true">×</button>
>                                   <h2 class="modal-title">Security Question</h2>
>                                   <hr class="colorgraph">
>
>                                   <div class="form-group">
>
>                                       <table>
>
>                                               <tr>
>                                               <td><label for="question">Security Question :
>                                               </label></td>
>                                               <td colspan="1"><label id="question" data-ng-model ="question">{{listOfUserQuesValues[0]}}
>                                               </label>
>                                               </td>
>                                           </tr>
>                                           <tr>
>                                               <td><label for="ans">Answer : </label></td>
>                                               <td colspan="1"><input type="text"
>                                                   data-ng-model="answer" /></td>
>                                           </tr>
>
>
>
>
>                                       </table>
>                                       <div class="form-group" style="padding: 20px 50px">
>                                           <input type="button" class="button" value=" Confrim"  data-ng-click="checkAnswer(answer)">
>                                           <input type="submit"  class="button" value=" Cancel" data-ng-click="cancel()">
>                                       </div>
>                                   </div>
>
>
>
>                               </div>
>                               <div class="modal-body"></div>
>                           </div>
>                       </div>
>               </fieldset>
>           </form>             </div>      </div>
> ```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Ksav How can I change my question dynamically on same window on confirm button click?